# jQuery - Simple Screensaver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to build a really simple screensaver, but it is not as easy as I thought.

My solution did not really work and it is IMHO really dirty.

Did anyone have a good clean idea? Maybe without a timeout?

**HTML**

```
<div id="screensaver" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#000000; display:none;" > &nbsp; </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $('body').live('mousemove', function (e)
    {

      if (e.type == 'mousemove')
      {
        clearTimeout(s_saver);
        s_saver = setTimeout('$(\'#screensaver\').fadeIn();', 4000);
        $('#screensaver').hide();          
      }

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwhJJ/4/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: look on this example : http://www.codeconnect.in/2010/09/jquery-bouncing-box-screensaver.html

Comment: Above link is no longer available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem with your script is that the `s_saver` variable is not declared properly, and is in the wrong scope - you need it to still be read the next time the event handler is called, so you should declare it outside the scope of the handler. This should work ([jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag9fr/)):

```
var s_saver;

$('body').mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(s_saver);

    s_saver = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#screensaver').fadeIn(900);
    }, 4000);

    $('#screensaver').fadeOut(100);
});
```

Of course this is still dependent on what you want to achieve. If, for instance, you want to show something while your user isn't looking at this particular tab/window instead of just not moving the mouse, then the solution provided in this question should do: [How to detect inactive tab and fill it with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563489/how-to-detect-inactive-tab-and-fill-it-with-color)

Comment: Any way to start the timeout on load?  When the page loads, the div is active and the screensaver is on until mouse is moved.

Answer (score -2):

Dont you think the browser will hang listening to contineous mouse move events....? not to demotivate you but just an idea.