# Add screensaver to website using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a website in asp.net c# that shows in a screen (LCD TV) the performance of a specific process. Every 15 secs the data is refreshed using below code:

```
<div id="InfoTop">
             <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;">                        
                        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                        <asp:Timer ID="tInfoTop" runat="server" Interval="15000"></asp:Timer>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upInfoTop" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tInfoTop" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>

                        <ContentTemplate>                                
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRemainingValuesTop" runat="server" Value="0" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIncrement" runat="server" Value="0" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEnd" runat="server" Value="0" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfShowCompleted" runat="server" Value="true" />                            
                            <asp:Table ID="InfoTopTable" Width="100%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" runat="server">                                    
                            </asp:Table>                            
                        </ContentTemplate>                        
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upaeTopPanel" runat="server" TargetControlID="upInfoTop" BehaviorID="animation">
                            <Animations>                                
                                <OnUpdated>
                                    <FadeIn Duration=".3" Fps="20" MaximumOpacity=".8"></FadeIn> 
                                </OnUpdated> 
                            </Animations>
                        </asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </div>
```

Now thinking about the possibility of damage the TV with the non-changing data like the header information. I'd like to add a screen saver to the whole screen, for instance, put  all the screen in black, then show an image or text, and finally return to show the information as before, all this every 10 mins.

I was looking at the solution by Yi Jiang ([jQuery - Simple Screensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745076/jquery-simple-screensaver)) but this works with the `mousemove` event, is there any way to change this code to make it work in time, every 10 mins for example? I was trying myself and couldn't do it :(

Or perhaps any other idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: LCD's don't suffer from burn-in.. not really a problem these days

Comment: Really? So I don't need to worry about that?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in#Plasma.2C_LCD_and_OLED_displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from the original StackOverflow screensaver link you posted:

```
var s_saver;

setInterval(function() {
    clearTimeout(s_saver);

    $('#screensaver').fadeIn(100);

    s_saver = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#screensaver').fadeOut(100);
    }, 5000);

}, 600000);
```

This will cause the #screensaver div to show for 5 seconds every 10 minutes.