# Set Timeout for screensaver

Tags: javascript, settimeout, screensaver, clearinterval

I have need a set timeout that will set the timeout after a inactive time, and then        initiate a screensaver, which plays a carousel of slides, when the user clicks on the screen it will restart the process with while starting the carousel back at the start of the slideshow. below is my code, any help is much appreciated thanks!

```
<script>
    /* The redirect to autoplay page function */
    var screenSaverDelay;
    var screenSaver;
    var destroySlider;

    $(document).ready(function(){

     setInterval(function(){window.focus();},1000);
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

    //var screenSaverDelay;

     $('body').click(function(event) {
       killScreenSaver();
     });

    function startScreenSaver() {
        clearTimeout(screenSaver);
        screenSaver=setTimeout(startScreenSaver,1000);
        $('#screensaver').show();
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }//end

   function killScreenSaver() {
      $('#screensaver').hide();
      $('.bxslider').destroySlider();
      clearTimeout(screenSaver);
      screenSaver=setTimeout(killScreenSaver,300000);
    }//end

    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){window.focus();},1000);
    });
    startScreenSaver();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? What error or mis-behavior are you getting?

Comment: Did you have a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745076/jquery-simple-screensaver) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a screensaver after a set amount of time, you shouldn't use setInterval, you should use setTimeout. You'll also want to bind something to your document that resets the timeout when the user clicks anywhere.

Change your doc.ready to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var screenSaverTime = 60000, // 1 minute
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() { startScreenSaver(); }, screenSaverTime);      

  $(document).bind(click, function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    myTimer = setTimeout(function() { startScreenSaver(); }, screenSaverTime);
  });
});
```

If you wanted to listen for lots of different activity and reset the timer on any of them, do something like this:

```
var resetTimer;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var screenSaverTime = 60000, // 1 minute
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() { startScreenSaver(); }, screenSaverTime);

  resetTimer = function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    myTimer = setTimeout(function() { startScreenSaver(); }, screenSaverTime);
  };

  $(document).bind(click, function() {
    resetTimer();
  }).mousemove(function() {
    resetTimer();
  });
});
```

Then you could call resetTimer from anywhere else in your script (so long as your document has already loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, this seems to be working correctly, cheers

```
<script>
    /* The redirect to autoplay page function */
    var screenSaverDelay;
    var screenSaver;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){window.focus();},1000);
        $('body').click(function(event) {
            killScreenSaver();
        });
        startScreenSaver();
    });

    function startScreenSaver() {
        clearTimeout(screenSaver);
        $('#screensaver').show();
        screenSaver = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }//end

    function killScreenSaver() {
       $('#screensaver').hide();
       screenSaver.destroySlider();
       clearTimeout(screenSaverDelay);
       screenSaverDelay=setTimeout(startScreenSaver,300000);
    }//end


    </script>
```