# Why this setTimeout() methods not working in this function?

Tags: javascript

```
function SlideShow(area)
    {
        var SlideImg = new Array('img1', 'img2');
        var SlideArea = document.getElementById(area);
        for(i=0;i<SlideImg.length;i++)
        {
            var html = '<img src="images/room/' + SlideImg[i] + '.jpg" id="' + SlideImg[i] + '" class="not-active" />';
            SlideArea.innerHTML += html;
        }
        var a = 0;
        function RunSlide()
        {
            document.getElementById(SlideImg[a]).className = 'active';
            a++;    
        }
        var run = setTimeout('RunSlide()', 5000);
    }
```

This function not working after I add the setTimeout() method there. Can anybody help me?

Comment: an aside, I'd make sure in your for loop to declare 'var i = 0' to avoid implicit globals.

Comment: You're passing a string to `setTimeout()` and that's generally a bad way to go.  The string will eventually be evaluated in the global scope, and in that context `RunSlide` will not be defined. By passing a **reference** to the function instead, the timeout sholuld work.

Answer (score 9):

Just change it to:

```
var run = setTimeout(RunSlide, 5000);
```

The reason is: when you pass a string to `setTimeout()` it is `eval`uated in global context - where `RunSlide` is not visible, because it is local.

Passing a string to `setTimeout()` is never a good idea, here you have one reason.

Comment: It doesn't work, or maybe the setTimeout() method cannot work if I put it in a function?

Comment: @EgaRana: can you wrap your code in a jsFiddle? How it *doesn't* work? Maybe you wanted to run your code in a "loop" (`setInterval()`)?

Comment: It's solved with your code, sorry it's my mistake before to put your code in wrong place. But what is the difference beetwen setTimeout(RunSlide, 5000) and setTimeout('RunSlide()', 5000)? I was read, to call a function it must call the function name in string.

Comment: @EgaRana: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals