# Write sequence of random numbers in javascript to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Really a newbie question but I can't seem to find the answer. I need to have this html file show a bunch of random numbers, separated by 1 second intervals. For some reason (maybe obvious) it is only showing me the last one unless I have 1 alert after each random number generated. How can I correct this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomnumber
var message

function placePossibleWinner()
{
randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
message="Teste ";
message=message.concat(randomnumber.toString());
document.getElementById("WINNER").innerHTML=message;
//alert(".")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function runDraw()
{
    var i=1
    alert("start")
    while (i<20)
  {
        setTimeout("placePossibleWinner()",1000)
        i++
  }
}
</script>

<h1>H Draw</h1>

<p id="WINNER">Draw</p>
<p></p>
<button onclick="runDraw()">Get me winner!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any answers/comments.

Comment: Side note: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`!  Pass functions.  `setTimeout(placePossibleWinner, 1000)`

Comment: Tried that and it still only shows me the first one. :(

Comment: That wasn't a solution, it was just an FYI.

Comment: I know. I just gave it a try in case that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is all your `setTimeout`s are being triggered at the same time.  Adding `alert`s pauses the JavaScript execution, so you see each number.  Without that, after 1 second, all 19 `setTimeout`s run (one after another) and you just see one number (the screen is updated so fast, you just see one).

Try using `setInterval` instead.

```
function runDraw() {
    var i = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < 20){
            placePossibleWinner();
            i++;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}​
```

This will run the function once every second, until `i` is 20, then it will clear the interval.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `setInterval` instead. using `setTimeout` in a loop will just queue up 20 calls immediately and they will all fire at once 1 second later. Also, you are setting the `innerHTML` of the `p` which will overwrite any previous text.

```
function placePossibleWinner() {
    // add a var here, implicit global
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

    // add a var here, implicit global
    message="Teste " + randomnumber + '\n'; // new line

    document.getElementById("WINNER").innerHTML += message; // concat, don't assign
}

function runDraw() {
    var counter = 1;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        if (counter < 20) {
            placePossibleWinner();
            counter++;
        } else {
           clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting your message in your functions and you are calling placePossibleWinner()  the wrong way... you want to use setInterval.  Below is a modification of your html/javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randomnumber;
    var message = "Teste ";
    var timesCalled = 0;
    var funtionPointer;

    function placePossibleWinner()
    {
        timesCalled++;
        randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        message=message.concat(randomnumber.toString());
        document.getElementById("WINNER").innerHTML=message;
        if (timesCalled > 20)
        {
         clearInterval(functionPointer);
        }
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runDraw()
    {
        var i=1
        alert("start")
        functionPointer = setInterval(placePossibleWinner,1000)
    }
</script>

<h1>H Draw</h1>

<p id="WINNER">Draw</p>
<p></p>
<button onclick="runDraw()">Get me winner!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval`!  Pass functions.  `setInterval(placePossibleWinner,1000)`

Answer (score 0):

To start with,

```
setTimeout("placePossibleWinner()",1000)
```

should be

```
setTimeout(placePossibleWinner,1000)
```

The parameter to setTimeput should be a reference to a function. See [JavaScript,setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)