# jQuery add delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to add delay in jquery. I was trying to put `$('.fade_test').delay(5000);` It is working but div last three is no next to start one.

Link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb5rt/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fadein">
<div class="fade_test">one <button id="toggler" class="playin">Pause</button></div>
<div class="fade_test">two <button id="toggler" class="playin">Pause</button></div>
<div class="fade_test">three <button id="toggler" class="playin">Pause</button></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; }
.fadein .fade_test { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

**JS**

```
var pauseplay;    

function startFader() {


    $x = $(".fade_test:visible").fadeOut(1000);
    $next = $x.next();
    if ($next.length == 0)
        $next = $(".fade_test:first-child");

    $next.fadeIn(1000);
    $('.fade_test').delay(5000);
}

function stopFader(){
    window.clearInterval(pauseplay);
console.log("stop");
}

   $('.fadein .fade_test:gt(0)').hide();

  pauseplay= window.setInterval(startFader, 2000);


var $button = $('.fadein #toggler');
$button.toggle(function() {
stopFader();  
$(this).toggleClass('playin pausin');
 $(this).text("Play");   
}, function() {

$(this).toggleClass('pausin playin');
 $(this).text("Pause");   
    pauseplay= window.setInterval(startFader, 2000);

});
```

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not JQuery but you could use Javascript's very simple setTimeout(fn,milliseconds);

**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)** is another post explaining

```
function foo(){
   alert('foo');
}

setTimeout(foo,1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Adam

setTimeout(function () { ? }, 10000);   how can put variable onto the function for fade_test?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do.  You might want to clarify the purpose of everything in your original question.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$('.fade_test');}, 10000); It is working! Briliant! Thanks Adam.

Comment: Just found other problem. When click to internet browser tab open but came back to page, problem the timeout.

Comment: use jquery blind window blur  - $(window).bind('blur', function() { });