# Javascript countdown timer that visually counts from 'hours:minutes:seconds' using PHP Date info & variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I have a PHP script that calculates the difference between a set date and the current date (in h:m:s) and I'd like to use that data for a simple visual Javascript countdown timer (using the PHP variables). This is the PHP code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', time());
$d1 = new DateTime("2012-11-18 11:14:15");
$d2 = new DateTime($date);
$result = $d1->diff($d2);
$hours = ($result->d*24)+$result->h;
$minutes = $result->i;
$seconds = $result->s;
```

What would be your preferred and most efficient way to display a countdown timer in Javascript? (Using either $d1 and $d2 or $hours, $minutes, $seconds?)

Comment: use [setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout) on a one-second loop.

Comment: Edited the post to explain I require a visualized countdown timer. I should've been more elaborate about what I meant. Apologies!

Comment: It sounds like you want someone to write the complete JavaScript code for you. StackOverflow doesn't work that way. Please try something yourself, and then post a question here when you have a specific problem with that code.

Comment: Dude, "That data" is on the server. JavaScript is on the client. Your design pattern makes no sense.

Comment: I have made several attempts to create it but the code simply wasn't working (my current Javascript knowledge is quite limited). I could post that code to have someone who wishes to help inspect it, tell me it's completely wrong and help me with a working solution, or I could save some people's time by not having to bother them to read my 'code of shame'.

Comment: well it's not that rare to initialize javascript variables with PHP ones o.O.

Comment: Diodeus, I thought using Javascript variables with PHP is a common occurence? At least I do it regularly. Either way your personal take on my design pattern isn't helping me find a solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use some Jquery plugin, like this one: [Jquery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

If you don't want to use plugins the general idea is this:

1. PHP writes the starting datetime to a HTML tag or to a javascrit variable.

   `echo '<div id="year">$year</div>';`
2. In javascript you create a function that decreases a current datetime by 1 second, decreasing minutes, hours, etc, when necessary.

   `function decrease_by_1_sec(){
        ...
   }`
3. Next, on the $(document).ready() function you make the `decrease_by_1_sec()` function execute every second.

   `setInterval(decrease_by_1_sec(), 1000);`

And that's it! that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery countdown plugin - http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html