# Call function in custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how this custom jQuery functions work by experimenting a bit. I can't however get it to work properly. I'm trying to call the `prepareSlide` function in my setInterval but it says `prepareSlide is not defined`

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('.item_holder').itemSlider({
        start: 1,
        carousel: true
    });
});
$.fn.itemSlider = function (details) {
    var currentSlideNumber = (details && details.start > 0) ? details.start : 1;
    this.prepareSlide = function(slideNumber) {
        alert(1)
    }
    //Set an interval
    var itemToSlide = currentSlideNumber + 1;
    slideTimer = setInterval("prepareSlide(" + itemToSlide + ")", 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should provide a function to the first argument of `setInterval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313023/575527). Also, to provide the context properly to the function invocation, a quick method is to preserve `this` by having another variable reference it, which in this case, we call `self`

```
var self = this;

slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
  self.prepareSlide(itemToSlide)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And what if i wanted to call the prepareSlide from outside too? `<a href="#" class="number" onclick="itemSlider.prepareSlide(1);" id="number_1">&nbsp;</a>`