# Calling function in custom function from 'outside'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just asked this question ([Call function in custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353972/call-function-in-custom-function/16354057?noredirect=1#16354057)) to find out how to call a function within a custom function and it works great. I would like to use the `prepareSlide` function on my onClick in my HTML too however. How can i call the `prepareSlide` within this `itemSlider` function?

```
jQuery('.item_holder').itemSlider();

$.fn.itemSlider = function (details) {
    var itemHolder = this;
    this.prepareSlide = function(slideNumber) {
        alert(1);
    }

    itemHolder.prepareSlide(1);
}
```

The `itemSlider` function adds pagination at the bottom of the slider with onClick to navigate to a certain slide right away(That's how it should work atleast) like so:

```
<a href="#" class="number" onclick="prepareSlide(1);" id="number_1">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add it to an onClick event, and even if you could, you shouldn't.

The function you have written adds the prepareSlide() functionality to jQuery, which means it needs to be called on a jQuery object. You will be unable to access that method outside of jQuery.

This is actually a good thing for you, since you shouldn't be using onClick attributes in your HTML, anyway. jQuery's event-handling model is more powerful and more flexible, and could be accessed via something like:

```
$('#number_1').on('click', function () {
     $('.item_holder').prepareSlide(1);
});
```

This is actually one of (IMHO) jQuery's most useful functionalities, easy access to the event and document object models. If you're feeling ambitious, you can change the selector to $('.number') and adjust your code to extract the number from the id field, and cover the entire list in 3 or 4 lines of code.

Comment: I'm using a user defined function which contains the prepareSlide function. Your method doesn't work with this construction. Especially considering i'm building the numbers on the fly(Depending on how many there are)

Comment: Correction: With some additions of my own this does work within the object. I'm using `this` instead of `$('.item_holder')` though