# Understand Ajax XMLHttpRequest in details

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to Ajax, and to make things worse, also a Javascript noob, and I have posted the bellow code of a chat script, to retrieve text from db,  in real time, and the code is working, but I need to understand what certain requests are all about.

```
<script>

function retrieve(){

    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        else {
            alert('Please update your browser to start chatting');
    }
```

Simply, I understand the above is (I created it) just a function with global variable declared to be assigned whether XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject Object is declared depending if browser is IE6,7 and others if not throw in alert...

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
```

Similarly, the above I assume takes the  `onreadystatechange` property of the Ajax API and checks for it's state, `readyState` & `status` which, if only they match 4 and 200 means, Ajax is working as wanted

```
t = setTimeout("retrieve()", 2000);
```

I know the `setTimeout()` is a bit like `setInterval()` function, which runs the function inside it, every 2 seconds, to check for new messages.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getajax.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Now, the problem is with the above, I can almost understand that the `.open` method is supposed to get data from `getajax.php` even though, I have no idea of what `true` means in this instance, but as far as the `xmlhttp.send();` I have absolutely no clue,

So, All I need is for you to explain to me what I have missed during my illaboration, and 
what the last queries mean, just in brief.

```
  }
    retrieve();

</script>

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: your code actually runs `retrieve()` recursively without a `2000ms` delay after the first `setTimeout` call executed. inside the retrieve function you should once more call: `setTimeout(retieve, 2000);`.   
Also note how I pass in the **function** itself instead of a **string** to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getajax.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

`true` is what tells the request to be performed **A** -synchronously, which is the **A** in AJAX. Then finally `.send()` actually send the request.

Asynchronous requests are non-blocking meaning that the rest of your code wont wait for them to finish and return before continuing. That is why you sent event handlers before starting the request via `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`. That way once the request is complete you have already told your script what to do with the returned information.

Hope this helps.

**Edit** Additionally I recommend using some sort of framework or library for javascript like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). While it is good to learn some of the javascript core, something like jQuery will make your life much easier.

Comment: while JQuery is handy in certain situations, for what he is describing it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

> Simply, I understand the above is (I created it) just a function with global variable declared to be assigned

`xmlhttp` isn't a global. It's a local variable in the global function `retrieve`.

> Similarly, the above I assume takes the onreadystatechange property of the Ajax API and checks for it's state

`onreadystatechange` is a property that accepts a function. That function is run when the value of `readyState` changes. That function is usually used to check the status of the request.

> I know the setTimeout() is a bit like setInterval() function, which runs the function inside it, every 2 seconds, to check for new messages.

`setTimeout` is like `setInterval` in a sense that it runs a function at a later time. Unlike `setInterval`, it only runs the code once. Also, that's not the proper way of running a timer. Here's [a post that explains how to properly use timers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313023/575527).

> the .open method is supposed to get data from getajax.php even though, I have no idea of what true means in this instance, but as far as the xmlhttp.send(); I have absolutely no clue

The `open` builds your request by accepting:

- The type of request (GET/POST)
- The url where you want the request sent
- The third argument determines if the request is asynchronous or not.

  - If set to `false`, this makes the request synchronous. The browser will freeze and wait for the response.
  - If `true`, the request us asynchronous. The browser will not freeze in waiting.

  The default value is `true`, so you can omit it.

`send` is the actual function that ultimately sends the request to the server.

For further reading, I suggest you read [MDN's section regarding AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).