# How do I make this script appear/activate a few seconds after loading?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like this script to appear online after the page has loaded 10 seconds in. It uses jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        var cookieSet = document.cookie.indexOf("eu_cookie=") != -1;
        if(!cookieSet)
            {
            $("#cookie_btn").click(function(){
                var expire = new Date();
                expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + 30);
                document.cookie = "eu_cookie=1; path=/; expires=" + expire;
                $(".cookie_wrap").fadeOut("slow");
            });
            $("#nothank").click(function(){
                var expire = new Date();
                expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + 30);
                document.cookie = "eu_cookie=1; path=/; expires=" + expire;
                $(".cookie_wrap").fadeOut("slow");
            });
            }
        else
            $(".cookie_wrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    </script>';
```

It code was created by someone else, and I am totally javascript illiterate. If you provide a solution, could you tell me how to implement it as well?

Comment: How does a script "appear online" :P ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript,setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function () {
        var cookieSet = document.cookie.indexOf("eu_cookie=") != -1;
        if(!cookieSet)
        {
            $("#cookie_btn").click(function(){
                var expire = new Date();
                expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + 30);
                document.cookie = "eu_cookie=1; path=/; expires=" + expire;
                $(".cookie_wrap").fadeOut("slow");
            });
            $("#nothank").click(function(){
                var expire = new Date();
                expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + 30);
                document.cookie = "eu_cookie=1; path=/; expires=" + expire;
                $(".cookie_wrap").fadeOut("slow");
            });
        }
        else $(".cookie_wrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }, 10000);
});
</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. However, the script still appears to load instantly. It doesn't wait for 10 seconds.

Comment: If that's the case then something else is wrong. Try this for example: setTimeout(function () { alert('works!'); }, 10000); and you'll see that the alert is fired after 10 seconds. (You can try it straight into the Chrome dev tools js-console if you want to.)

Comment: Thanks, would anyone else have any other suggestions?