# Start function after a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can start function after a time , for exampl e:

```
<script>
function alert()
{

alert("Execute alert after 5 seconds");

}
</script>


alert();
```

I need inside function tell execute after 5 seconds , how i can do this , i need this control inside function no in other function or external , inside of alert function the control for launch the function after 5 seconds for example

After this time the function must be execute finally

Thank´s Regards

Comment: [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript,setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? It is great and does all things.

Comment: @simonzack jquery is not everything and there were great things before jquery.. :)

Comment: Thank´s all people put me negatives , :) very nice people no ? hahahaha

Comment: And you put duplicate my question and it´s the same user as me ???? put the question there , hahaha incredible great people here yes yes , moderate my eggs

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript's `setTimeout` function.

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello World!"); }, 5000)
```

(The parameters are function and milliseconds before it executes)

Comment: Oh man it's  `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut` check my answer .