# Day/night image change

Tags: php, image, time

I want an image on my website that changes every hour, when its 8AM I want `image1.png` if it is 9AM I want `image2.png` if it is 10AM I want `image1.png` again and this for all hours.

All the hours you can divide by 2 have to be `image1.png`, else it has to be `image2.png`.
I don't know how to do this :S Can someone help?

I tried something like this:

```
    <?php

date_default_timezone_set("Netherlands/Amsterdam");
$now = date('G');

if ($now > 7 && $now < 20) {
    $day=1;
} else {
    $day =0;
}
?>

if ($day=1){
echo 'day!';
}
else
{
echo 'night :(';
}

?>
```

But it also dont echo day or night.

Comment: change `if ($day=1)` to `if ($day == 1)`

Comment: And remove the `?>` in the middle of your code.

Comment: did you consider checking sunset time instead of explicitly specifying day and night times? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sunset.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if ($day==1){
    echo 'day!';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'night :(';
    }
```

Using "=" means You are not checking value, but assigning

Comment: Thanks, but how can i change it so the image changes every hour? Or do i have to make 24 if-statements?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code that solves your questions, the image name should be the hour of the day (24 hour format), for example 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Netherlands/Amsterdam");
$now = date('G');

$imageSrc = "images/" . now . ".jpg";

echo '<img src="' . $imageSrc . '" alt="" />';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = date('G');

if ($now > 7 && $now < 20) {
    $hr = $now - 7;
    $pic = "image{$hr}.png";
} else {
    $pic = "image1.png";
}

echo "<img src='$pic'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, English is not my Mother-tongue, but your intention is difficult to comprehend.

> All the hours you can divide by 2 have to be image1.png, else it has to be image2.png. I don't know how to do this :S Can someone help?

You say you want to change the picture every hour, so if the hour is even (2,4,6,8, ... 24/0) you want picture1 displayed and else you want to show picture2.

But going after your code example you only check if it's day or night oO

```
if ($now > 7 && $now < 20) {
    $day=1;
} else {
    $day =0;
}
?>

if ($day=1){
echo 'day!';
}
else
{
echo 'night :(';
}
```

So what exactly do you want to achieve?

For the former just try to work with modulo, something like:

```
$now = Date('G');

if(($now % 2) == 1)
{
echo "$now is odd, so display picture2";
} else {
echo "$now is even, so display picture1";
}
```

if you want both, just combine them :) No need for 24 if-statements, modulo is what you want (http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

If you want 24 different pictures (which I couldn't read out of your question), then go for another solution, like the one mentioned below mine ;)

I'm sorry if I got you wrong!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve that in real time then you can use polling method in which a function will be executed after every 1hour to change the image dynamically

setTimeout(function(){/* javascript function which will change the image */},60000);

Check the site below-

[JavaScript.setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Hope it will help.

Cheers!