# Comparing arrays to calculate the grade

Tags: php

My student.php page: Displayin questions with their multiple choices randomly from database

```
 <form name="f1" id=f1 method="get" action="submittingquiz.php">
        <?php
        $correct=array();

      $query=  mysql_query("select 
     question_number,question_description,correctanswer_id from 
     quizzesbankofquestion where course_code='MATH220' && quiz_level='1' && 
     level_of_difficulty='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
     if (!$query) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
       $row=  mysql_num_rows($query); 
      if($row!=0){

      while($questions=  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          $correct=array($questions[2]);
          $_SESSION['array']=$correct;
        echo "<table>
         <tr><td> $questions[0]</td>
                  <td>$questions[1]</td> </tr>";

          $choices=  mysql_query("select choices_id,choices_descriptions
        from quiz_choices where course_code='MATH220' && 
        question_number='$questions[0]'ORDER BY RAND() ");

          if (!$choices) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

          while($questionchoices=  mysql_fetch_array($choices)){

             echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' value='$questionchoices[0]' 
          name='$questions[0]'/>$questionchoices[1]</td></tr></table>";}
           }}?>
    <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
```

Submitting.php

```
  <?php

    require_once 'connect.php';
    session_start();
    $numCorrect = 0;
    $answers=array();

    if(isset($_SESSION['array'])){
         print_r ($_SESSION['array']); //it is not printing the same array as $correct,It is only printing one element
        $correct=$_SESSION['array'];

    foreach($correct as $key=>$val){
       $answers=$_GET['$questions[0]'];//trying to get the values of the radio buttons and store it in array
        print_r($answers);// displaying Array word only

   if($val = $answers[$key]){
   $numCorrect++;
    }
     }  }?>
```

The array session is not displayed the same,also I didn't know how can I fill the value of the radio buttons in the array.I am trying to compare the correct answers.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I doubt you searched alot. I found a solution by simply typing: `javascript timer` into google search.

Comment: check this out ....http://jquerytimer.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for a simple JavaScript countdown timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 0):

You want javascript's [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

More information is available at this answer: [JavaScript.setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Answer (score 0):

this script will count down in seconds and redirect to a new page once finish

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>test countdown</title>   
</head>
<body>

<span id="counter">10</span>


 <script type="text/javascript">
        function countdown() {
            var i = document.getElementById('counter');
                if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
                   location.href = 'new.html';
                }
                i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
            }
            setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to take the time from input, which i presume you got it from the previous page that post the form using get method, then you want to use php 

$countdown_time = @$_GET['time'];

then edit <span id="counter">$countdown_time</span>