# jQuery Hover with Delay when the user moves their mouse away

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

So I am trying to achieve a popup situation, where the user will hover over one element, when the user hovers over this element, jQuery adds a class to another sibling element which makes it visible. When the user hovers out I'd like to add a delay of like 5 seconds before the class is removed again, but my attempts to do this have not worked out thus far, can anybody give me a pointer on what method I can use?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
$('.spaceship-container').hover(
function(){
    $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').addClass('show')
},
function(){
    setTimeout(3000);
    $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').removeClass('show')
}
);
```

Comment: like this?     $('.spaceship-container').hover(
 function(){
  $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').addClass('tmtyn')
 }, setTimeout(3000, function(){ $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').removeClass('tmtyn')
 });

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript.setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using proper syntax of [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function fixes your issue. But you also need to stop mouseout function using [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).

```
var timer;
$('.spaceship-container').hover(
  function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').addClass('show');
  },
  function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').removeClass('show');
    }, 3000);
  }
);
```

Comment: Whilst this answer is also correct, I will elect the one by @Guruprasad-Rao correct due to adding a level of explanation in to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardGrandi. I agree with Rejith, you might want to clear the `timeout` again if you are allowing user to hover the element again, unless you cover the whole stuff with some overlay.. :) +1 for good thinking Rejith..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `removeClass` inside the callback of `setTimeout` as below:

```
$('.spaceship-container').hover(
function(){
    $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').addClass('show')
},
function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
         $('.take-me-to-your-newsletter').removeClass('show') //here
    },3000);
});
```

So that once the 3 seconds time is completed, the lines inside the callback function will get executed.

Plus a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jgmo33qw/)** for you