# I have a JSON file on server I want to display it in JQuery data table with searching, sorting and pagination

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html

The JSON file is dynamic. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Amount </th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>PID</th>
                <th>Special Instructions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/annxmks9/

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using datatable to achieve your goal. I refer to the [official documentation](https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax)

> **Loading data**
>
> Ajax data is loaded by DataTables simply by using the ajax option to set the URL for where the Ajax request should be made. For example, the following shows a minimal configuration with Ajax sourced data:
>
> ```
> $('#myTable').DataTable( {
>   ajax: '/api/myData'
> } );
> ```

If your table should be refreshed at time you can set a [timeout function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout) and call the [Datatable `ajax.reload()` function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Here is an example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```