# Automatically updating a socket connections data? socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I would like to periodically update the data sent to all the connected clients, over the socket.io connection, does socket.io have a function or feature for doing this?

Comment: socket.io do not have this feature. You can do it manually by setting timer function and simple socket.io.emit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you don't need to worry about synchronising data with Socket.io. Simply because it's bi-directional & event-based.
But you still can update stream from server or client side based on events.

Take a look at this [article](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio/)

To make the update periodic (based on time), you can use `setTimeout()` function in Javascript.
More on that in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.sockets.emit('an event for everybody', { some: 'data' });
```

If you're not calling this on a specific connection it will broadcast to all connected clients.