# session timeout,alert not displaying message

Tags: php, session-timeout

I have a page that logs users out after 10 seconds of idling,but it does so without displaying a message and I need to refresh the page to show that I'm logged out. How do I display a message like "Logged out due to inactivity" with an okay button and when I click on it, it redirects back to index.php?

```
session_start();
$timeout = 10;
// Check if the timeout field exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
// See if the number of seconds since the last
// visit is larger than the timeout period.
$duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];
if($duration > $timeout) { 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Your session will expire soon!");
<?php header("location:../../index.php"); ?>
</script>
<?php

}
// Destroy the session and restart it.
session_destroy();
session_start();

}

// Update the timout field with the current time.
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Comment: Your `header()` redirects before the alert is shown on page. Use `window.location.href='';` in javascript.

Comment: the alert popup is still not showing

Comment: Then test all values, also do an `console.log('i was executed')`, by the way use F12 developer console to check javascript issue/bugs.  And maybe you have to use an `setTimeout()`  before the redirect to give alert time to open the box. Try some.

Comment: got it to work.thanks!

Comment: currently I need to hit refresh button after 10 seconds to trigger the alert box. Is there any way for the box to show up automatically after 10 seconds?

Comment: `setTimeout()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout#10313023