# word does not display in Chrome until you end the shuffle

Tags: javascript

In this program below, the variable word does not display in any browser every time you shuffle.

```js
let word = prompt("Enter a word:");

while (true) {
    let scramble = scrambleWord(word);
    displayWord(scramble);

    let again = prompt("Scramble again? (y/n)");
    if (again === "n") {
        break;
    }
}

function scrambleWord(word) {
    word = word.split("").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).join("");
    return word;
}

function displayWord(scramble) {
    let displayArea = document.getElementById("display-area");
    displayArea.innerHTML = scramble;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="display-area"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Regards,
Lee

the word should appear each time it's shuffled.

Comment: I believe the loop is blocking the renderer from updating. [HTML page doesn't update while a javascript function running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55091016)

Comment: Do you have to use `prompt` in this assignment? If not, then try to implement it using a `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `prompt()` method blocks the JavaScript execution and does not allow the webpage to update and display the `id="display-area"` div element. As a result the code you provided wont appear each time it's shuffled.

Instead, what you can do is add a `button` instead of a prompt and add an `Event Listener`.

Below, I edited your code to show how you can achieve your desired output using button and `Event Listener` instead of `prompt`.

```js
let scrambleButton = document.getElementById("scramble-button");
        scrambleButton.addEventListener("click", scrambleWord);
        function scrambleWord() {
            let word = document.getElementById("word-input").value;
            let scramble = word.split("").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).join("");
            let displayArea = document.getElementById("display-area");
            displayArea.innerHTML = "Original Word: " + word + "<br>Scrambled Word: " + scramble;
        }
```

```html
<div id="display-area"></div>
<input type="text" id="word-input">
<button id="scramble-button">Scramble</button>
```

Explanation: The `word input` **id** input element accepts data from the user. Whenever the `scramble-button` **id** button element is clicked, it will trigger the Event Listener calling the `scrambleWord()` and shuffle the word. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly what you want it´s necessary to put the prompt function inside a promisse and use a setTimeout() function to wait a minimum time to let the browse display the tag  in the page.

like this:

```js
function displayWord() {
  getPrompt().then((word) => {
    if (word !== 'n') {
      document.getElementById('display-area').textContent = word
        .split('')
        .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        .join('');
      displayWord();
    }
  });
}

function getPrompt() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(prompt('Enter a word (enter \'n\' to exit):'));
    }, 30);
  });
}

displayWord();
```

```html
<div id="display-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but
I think this might be due to the script loading before your DOM tree is finished loading. you can fix this by adding the defer tag after your script

Try it out and let me know if it worked :)

src = https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Comment: It's not it. You can clearly see that the code is placed AFTER the relevant element. And you can't use `async`/`defer` on inline script

Answer (score -1):

As explained by @JohnnyMopp in the first comment, *the loop is blocking the renderer from updating*. But if you don't have to use `prompt` for this assignment then you can implement the main functionality using a `form` with a text field, where the user enter the word, and a submit button that will scramble the word when you click on it:

```js
document.getElementById("word-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let word = document.getElementById("word").value;
  let scramble = scrambleWord(word);
  displayWord(scramble);
});

/*let word = prompt("Enter a word:");

while (true) {
    let scramble = scrambleWord(word);
    displayWord(scramble);

    let again = prompt("Scramble again? (y/n)");
    if (again === "n") {
        break;
    }
}*/

function scrambleWord(word) {
    word = word.split("").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).join("");
    return word;
}

function displayWord(scramble) {
    let displayArea = document.getElementById("display-area");
    displayArea.innerHTML = scramble;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="word-form">
    <label>
      Enter a word:
      <input type="text" name="word" id="word" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

  </form>
  <div id="display-area"></div>
</body>

</html>
```